# Fetching child tags of a tag with a xmlns namespace

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following xml document:

```xml
<reply xmlns:j="http://abc/1">
    <alarm xmlns="http://abcs/1/alarm">
        <alarm-sum>
            <no-active-alarms/>
        </alarm-sum>
    </alarm>
    <clix>
        <banner></banner>
    </clix>
</reply>
```

The end goal is just to determine if `<no-active-alarms/>` tag is there in the document or not.

But this tag is also represented as `{http://abc/1/alarm}no-active-alarms` and the namespace associated might change so I don’t want to hardcode it. Is there a way in python to ignore the associated namespace? I don't want to modify the XML.

Comment: Why would the namespace change? The URI in the namespace is part of the identity of the tag, `{http://example.com}no-active-alarms` is a completely different tag from `{http://example.org}no-active-alarms`, because the two URIs are different. Are you certain you want to allow for *any* URI namespace and just match any `no-active-alarms` tags?

Comment: Note that the namespace URI differs from namespace *prefixes*, like the `xmlns:j="..."` attribute on the root `<reply>` tag; prefixes are document-local and just a way to use a short 'variable' for a namespace URI. Prefixes can change, URIs will not.

Comment: Also, can you clarify if you are using just the [standard library `xml.etree.ElementTree` API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or the [more powerful lxml library built on the same API](https://lxml.de/index.html)? If you are not using lxml now, is it an option for you to use `lxml` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are multiple XMLs, the URI may change for them but the 'no-active-alarms' will not. I would prefer a generalized solution this is not dependent on the namespace. And yes, Ixml is not an option unfortunately

Comment: That's rather odd and broken behaviour, for a system to generate tags with the same name but under different namespaces, but having the same meaning.